# Redirect e Render no Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho um arquivo `views.py` que possui o seguinte método:

```
def alterar(request, pk):
    cliente = get_object_or_404(Cliente, pk=pk)    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST, instance = cliente)
            if form.is_valid():
                cliente = form.save(commit=False)
                cliente.save()
                cliente_listar = Cliente.objects.all()
                return render(request, 'cliente/listar.html', {'cliente' : cliente_listar}) 
    else:
        form = ClienteForm(instance=cliente)
        return render(request, 'cliente/cadastro.html', {'form' : form})
```

O meu problema está no `render()` do `POST`, pois ao voltar para **url** de **listar** ainda fica com a seguinte **url**: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cliente/alterar/5/`, mas com a página de **listar**, o certo ao meu ver teria que ser: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cliente/listar/`.

Em algumas pesquisas encontrei o `redirect()` mas igual a **url** fica nesse formato: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cliente/alterar/5/cliente/listar.html` na qual acaba dando erro.

Estou usando **Python 3.5** e **Django 1.10**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função render() não altera a url, apenas o que é exibido por ela. O correto realmente seria você usar o redirect() em conjunto com o reverse(). O trabalho do reverse é encontrar a url completa pelo nome e não pelo link, bem como montá-la com os parâmetros. Eis um exemplo:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('listar', kwargs={'cliente': 5}))
```

Claro que vai depender de como está seu urls.py e os parâmetros que a sua url "listar" precisa.

Fonte: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse